# GitBlit - How to ignore space changes

Tags: git, gitblit

We are using GitBlit to run a simple git repository and also use it to see the differences between files for a particular commit. I am looking for a setting which can force gitblit to ignore the unimportant difference like line ending or spaces and show just what is really changed. This works pretty well if I type gitk in git bash and check the checkbox for "Ignore Space Change".

Note: I am a Git beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Gitblit, as of 1.3.1, does not (yet) have controls for ignoring whitespace changes.

Gitblit as of 1.7.x has configurable whitespace support on diffs.

Comment: Gitblit 1.7.x now has configurable whitespace support on diffs.